# Prevent parsing of to-be-parsed HTML elements with Bash

Tags: php, html

I have a LAMP (CentOS) "shared" server environment on which I can't control Apache webserver fully but partially through `.htaccess` files;
I can SSH that environment and use Bash in my user partition.
On that environment I have a MediaWiki website.

MediaWiki core includes some features I would like to disable but doesn't allow the option to do so (for example, one cannot disable edit summary boxes or footer links).

As I am not a PHP programmer and don't want to change the massive core PHP, I thought to prevent such features from being parsed to client, somehow.

- Disabling these through CSS and/or JavaScript isn't an option because a user can disable CSS and/or JS and then use these features
- I thought to prevent the parsing of such features while PHP document still gets executed in a similar scenario:
  Some PHP function gets called before any PHP line or routine gets executed (for processing markup);
  Then, by some criterion (CSS class maybe), that function filters out that line or routine from being executed, thus the HTML structure that would otherwise be parsed by it, won't be parsed
  But PHP 7.3.11 doesn't have such a function.

**Is there any tweak to prevent parsing of to-be-parsed HTML elements with Bash?**

Comment: Are you sure you can't do what you want by changing your MediaWiki config? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuration_settings

Comment: @Mat not all changes are available from there; in in any case I prefer to know such a way (as described in question).

Comment: Someone that know MediaWiki would possibly be able to help you if you actually told them what features you are trying to disable. Are you only interested in the summary boxes and footer links?

Comment: @Kusalananda not necessarily. I already consulted the MW community about these two matters; in both, as I recall, CSS/JS were mentioned...

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do this with bash; beyond the fact that it happens to be your webhost's default shell, it doesn't seem relevant in any way. In any case, shell scripting of any kind is almost certainly not a good way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Also, you do know that MediaWiki also has a lot of [hooks](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Footer) for customization, right? For example, you can use hooks to [change the footer links](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Footer). You'll need to write a bit of PHP code to define a hook (technically, _all_ MediaWiki configuration is PHP code anyway), but it's mostly boilerplate. As long as you know how PHP functions and arrays work, you should be fine.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen hello; I know, but I didn't find suitable hook; the entire area of MediaWiki hooks seems to me somewhat misty and the documentation is often unclear (in my opinion, perhaps in purpose). AFAIR I already changed footer links from PHP but I know no hook (and a MediaWiki community mod didn't know either) a hook to disable summary boxes or elements in general by some criterion.

Comment: Depending on what you specifically want to do, the easiest option might be to make your own [skin](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Skins) for MediaWiki. There's a [tutorial](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Skinning_Part_1) for it, but basically you want to start by cloning an existing skin (either the default [Vector](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Skin:Vector) skin or maybe the [Example skin](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Skin:Example) from the tutorial). Then you can pretty much edit the HTML template any way you like.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I didn't think about this - thanks. Please consider copy pasting and editing the comments into an answer --- I will gladly give the bounty (otherwise it will demise and I can't take it back). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you would want to use bash or any other kind of shell scripting for this.  That's just not what it's made for.  For that matter, even if you used something that *was* designed for HTML manipulation, adding an extra transformation layer between MediaWiki and the user's browser just to avoid learning a small amount of PHP seems like a bad idea.

As an alternative solution, I would suggest configuring MediaWiki to generate the HTML you want directly.  Besides a large number of [configuration variables](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuration_settings), MediaWiki also allows provides programmable [hooks](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks) for modifying many parts of its operation.  For example, the [SkinTemplateOutputPageBeforeExec](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Manual:Hooks/SkinTemplateOutputPageBeforeExec) hook can be used to modify most of the inputs that go into the HTML template, including the [footer](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Footer) links.

If the flexibility offered by the hooks is not enough for what you want to do, another option is to make your own MediaWiki [skin](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Skins).  This will let you entirely replace the HTML template and customize it pretty much any way you want.  There's a [tutorial](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Skinning_Part_1) for making a new skin that you might want to take a look at, but basically the easiest way is to start by cloning an existing skin (such as the [Example skin](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Skin:Example) that comes with the tutorial, or the default built-in [Vector](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Skin:Vector) skin) and tweaking it until it works the way you want.